# Wrapping html to other half of the page on page break and handling headings after the page break

Tags: html, css

I've got a table with very few columns but many rows on an html document. I'm trying to save paper during printing and I'm wondering if there is a way to wrap the table to the other half of the page.

It needs to keep the headings of the table on the other half as well like it does during a page break.

Another issue that comes up is that there are nested headers that need to repeat as well. For example:
Heading 1 Company A
Heading 1.1 Branch A
Some Data
Heading 1.2 Branch B
Some Data
Heading 2 Company B
Heading 2.1 Branch C
Some Data
Heading 2.2 Branch D
Some Data

That means that if there is still data for either of the sub heading they also need to be repeated after the page break.

I'm also trying to use base html so I can't use any libaries.

So far I have tried using the normal html table and using flex box form of a table

Comment: Please also include the code that you tried, and explain what is not working in your code.